# how to integrate paypal Single Payment in a mobile app using rest api

Tags: ios, rest, symfony, paypal

I am integrating paypal sandbox single payment in IOS app.I am following the below solution.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md
My First IOS call give me the following sample response.

```
{
  "client":{
    "environment":"sandbox",
    "paypal_sdk_version":"2.0.0",
    "platform":"iOS",
    "product_name":"PayPal iOS SDK;"
  },
  "response":{
    "create_time":"2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
    "id":"PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
    "intent":"sale",
    "state":"approved"
  },
  "response_type":"payment"
}
```

Is there any solution to verifying and capturing the payment in my custom PHP API's where i can make paypal rest call using PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI id.

I am unable to find any code or example using PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI id?

Your help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending lot of time on internet. I finally solved this problem. On IOS side I will get the id and transactionID/captureID after that in my api I made the next call for authorize and capture.